# Python: Prevent certain packages to be imported by other packages

Tags: python, import, python-import

I have a project containing multiple packages for example:

```
production/
    __init__.py
    prod_module_1.py
    prod_subpackage/
        __init__.py
        prod_submodule_1.py
    ...
computation/
    __init__.py
    computation_module_1.py
    ...
development/
   ...
```

Now I want to prevent that specific packages can be imported by others. To go with the above example I want `development` modules to be able to import all types of packages but I don't want any module in `production` being able to import code from `development`. And in the same gist I want computation to be "standalone" so it can only import modules from itself, but it can be imported by other modules.

In the Python documentation https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html I found the following excerpt:

> To selectively prevent import of some modules from a hook early on the meta path (rather than disabling the standard import system entirely), it is sufficient to raise ModuleNotFoundError directly from find_spec() instead of returning None. The latter indicates that the meta path search should continue, while raising an exception terminates it immediately.

But I'm unsure how/where I need to overwrite this method. An insight on where in the code base these changes need to be made would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you want to start with https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#setting-up-an-importer, which appears to provide an example of adding a meta path finder to the import system.

Comment: I think you should reconsider your design, and decouple your code rather than implementing some workarounds to achieve what you should've achieved with a good design in the first place.